# How to make a column visible based on parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table column that is set to Visiblity: Hidden = True.

Now I want to make the column visible if the parameter equals 'Maths'.

I've currently selected the column and gone to Column Visivlity, 'Show or Hide based on an expression'

My expression is:

```
=IIf(Parameters!subjectParam.Value="Maths",False,True)
```

But for some reason it does not work?

Comment: Try converting the .value to a CStr before testing the ="Maths". So =IIf(CStr(Parameters!subjectParam.Value)="Maths",False,True). A shot in the dark...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good work around is sometimes to use field values from the **actual database or dataset** rather than the parameter.

So if the subject is math and certain columns are filtered then you could use that as visibility.

Something like:

```
 =IIF(Fields!MathColumnFieldValue.Value > 0, True, False)
```